# In-place swap load balancer listener

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have one load balancer with two attached listeners and I want to swap the ports being used to forward. Roughly speaking, I want

```
aws_lb "lb" {}
aws_lb_listener "listener1 {
  port = 80 -> 8080
}
aws_lb_listener "listener1 {
  port = 8080 -> 80
}
```

I get

> Error: Error modifying LB Listener: ValidationError: Listener port
>   '8080' is already in use  status code: 400

A workaround is to do

```
80 -> 8081
8080 -> 80
8081 -> 8080
```

But that's cumbersome. I'm tempted to just write a script but is a smart way where I can rely on terraform to do this in place?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Why do you care which listener has which port if it's the same LB?

Comment: I'm doing blue green where live is on 80 and new deployment is on 8080. I want to flip the ports to go live on the new deploy

Comment: @woton I'm facing the exact same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: as far as I can tell, this is not possible in tf. what I did was write up a quick python script.